# Trying to open a file in C error

Tags: c

I just started to learn C and came across this error when trying to run a simple program to open a .txt file.

[image: Sublime text editor code]

[image: MAC Terminal]

Comment: `fopen()` can return error, so check for that. And put code and error in the post rather than screenshots.

Comment: Further, you are using `"stdio.h"` instead of `<stdio.h>`.

Comment: Please make your answer complete by providing your code and the error message. Not as external links and not as pictures, please.

Comment: Print the return value of fopen() before trying to use it. It wouldn't happen to be zero, would it? Read a documenation of fopen(). It is what Rohan already tried to make you aware of.

Comment: Please post the code, not an image. You can format your code into a <pre> tag with Ctrl+K.

Comment: Why am I seeing `test.dat` in the code when you state `open a .txt file` in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to iterate through your file, test the pointer returned by fopen() :

```
if(!pToFile) // or if(pToFile == NULL) 
    exit(1); //exit the program
```